# Vet couldn't fix cat lower lip injury

Tags: cats, injury

Last Friday night my mother accidentally stepped on our 2-months old cat. She thought she had killed him so we went searching for a vet at 10 pm.

Fortunately, we found one willing to help us. He gave the cat two injections, perhaps an antibiotic and a sedative.

The cat slept all the way through Saturday. When he woke up he was able to eat but apparently he had trouble drinking. He seems to be fine, just a little sad.

Today we took him to the doctor again, as he was kind to attend us on Sunday. He told us there was no apparent fracture but the lower lip was hanging down quite a bit.

The vet tried to glue the cat's lower lip but it came loose shortly after. He then said he couldn't fix it.

What should I do? Please welp!

Comment: If I were you, I'd get a second vet opinion! Did they do an x-ray to check for the fracture? Maybe there's a dislocation or something else. Also, 2mo is pretty young - was the kitten properly weaned?

Comment: @Megan Thanks for comment! I will try again tomorrow with another vet. And yes the kitten is able to eat solids. I don't know his age for sure but he weights around two pounds (900 grams).